# Find the average value of a function on an interval given the function's derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm asked to find the **average value** of a function, on an interval [5,15] given its *rate of change* (derivative):

$ f(v)= 2*e^-0.4v-e^-0.12v $

When I integrate this function, I get: $(-2/0.4)*e^-0.4v +(1/0.12)*e^-0.12v+C$ (I was given some values so I also know that C=20 in the original function)

Since I believe this to be the primitive function F(v), should I integrate it **again** in order to evaluate it for 15 and 5? Or should I just plug in the values [5,15] (and multiply by 1/15-5) this same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average value of a function $f$ in the interval $[a,b]$ is given by $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx.$$

So you need to find $$f(v):=\int e^{-0.4v}-e^{-0.12v}dv$$ and then calculate $$\frac{1}{10}\int_5^{15} f(v)dv.$$

Comment: You’re welcome. Perhaps you could accept my answer :)